# Facebook Fans Page, FBML: Is it possible to update the content (image and text) directly from our site(php/mysql)?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

Facebook Fans Page, FBML: Is it possible to update the content (image and text) directly from our site(php/mysql)?

Please help me on this..

Thanks in advance,
Sandy

Comment: please specify your question. facebook stores static resources in fbml to prevent exactly that they change (e.g. are saved to user profiles and get swapped with advertisements). but it hink you are talking about the newsfeed? yeah, there apis for that... http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: Hi Joe,

I want to display our ad on the facebook page, I need an option to modify the content(image, text) from our own site, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fb:ref](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ref) to do that.

Just make sure you understand how to refresh Facebook's cache of this resource.